# How to add ASCI Char in TStringGrid Cells

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I'm not expert in Delphi  and I'm trying to add "Extended ASCII String" broken into individual character and then add into the TSgringGrid.Cells[x,y]. Some of the characters are getting displayed but rest of the characters are not shown in these cells. Another way for me is to convert these characters in Hex-Mode and then show it but this is not Required.

ChartSet used was OEM_CHARSET and Font = Terminal. I simply wish to display all 255 characters in Cell. Basically I wanted to created the Binary Editor like Edit.com in Delphi/ Lazarus which is available in XP.

Comment: I wonder which characters aren't being shown. I also wonder why. Is that also your question? You didn't say.

Comment: Yes. some of the characters are not getting shown. Ð   Ð                  ò<t‘à€       ™™™™™™™™ @      %) #sE)% 1UA@@„Äðððððððð#Eg‰õñ÷öñóððòóùùãÅÙÔÉÄðñÃÁÙÄ@ÁÃÃÅ×ãÖÙ@@ÁÃÁÃÉÙÅÙ@ÕÁÔÅ@@@@@@@@@@@@ÃÉãè@ÕÁÔÅ@@@@äâB@      `V #t#Eg‰

Comment: For example: Hex Values "02 C2" are not visible on Cell

Comment: Does the encoding you're using recognize those as valid AnsiString characters? Hex value 02 is not a printable character anyway. How many bits does each character have in your environment? (That is, is `Char` an alias for `AnsiChar` or `WideChar`?)

Comment: I'm using full set of 8 bits. I have to make sure 02 is displayed because I'm string to create the binary editor using StringGrid. Idealy there should be some way to show all 255 Ascii char. I've dedicated one cell each fro ascii char

Comment: Do you have some suggestion, so that I can use some other component to show the Asicii Characters (all 255). Just like MS XP's "edit.com" program shows all Ascii characters.

Comment: @SatyendraShukla: There are only 128 characters in the ASCII character set. You are obviously talking about some other character set.

Comment: No. There are 0 to 255 http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Text

Comment: and I almost worked up with  Terminal Font

Comment: The term *ASCII* appears just once on that page. Have you read that sentence carefully? It makes clear that it's talking about something *beyond* ASCII. ASCII has exactly 128 characters.

Comment: ASCII has 128 characters. The remainder (up to 255) are **extended ASCII**. Regardless, the code you've posted is meaningless without the additional information people are asking you for - [edit] your question and add the relevant information there instead of burying it in comments. Before doing so, use the debugger to step through the code to try to see what's happening yourself. Then you can add **specifics** that we can use to try and help you solve the problem.

Comment: AnsiToUtf8(chr(i) made my Day.

Comment: You have to know information about your encodings, and there's no such information here. Extended ASCII can mean many things. What do you mean?

Comment: Extended ASCII means 127+ characters used by IBM.

Answer (score 0):

I used `AnsiToUtf8(chr(i))` and it was solved.

Comment: Yes. It works because the string or char was converted to Extended IBC ASCII Chars. By default, the string as normal ASCII with 7-Bits. AnsiToUtf8(AnsiString(Decodeddata[i+1])) also worked. http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=18999.0